# Method that takes an integer input n and rotates an array n spaces

Tags: java, arrays, rotation

The my goal is to take a user's input and rotate the array however many times based off of their integer input. At first I was trying to get the array to reverse just to see it shift but I have a few errors in my function that won't let me compile.

Edit: I know I used list instead of using arr. I was looking at an example and accidentally typed it in.

Here is my code:

```java
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Project1P2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] arr1 = {2,4,6,8,10,12};
        int[] arr2 = shift(arr1);

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Here is the Array: " + arr1);
        System.out.println("Enter a number to shift array: ");
        int n = input.nextInt();
    }

    public static int[] shift(int[] arr) {
        int[] arrShiftDone = new int[list.length];
        for (int i = 0, j = arrShiftDone.length - 1; i < list.length; i++, j--) {
            arrShiftDone[j] = list[i];
        }
        return arrShiftDone;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your mistake is that in your shift method you are using `list`, it should be `arr`. I have updated it below. I have also included the shift method.
Edited to include negative shifts.

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] arr1 = {2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12};
    int[] arr2 = reverseArray(arr1);

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Here is the Array: " + Arrays.toString(arr1));
    System.out.print("Enter a number to shift array: ");
    int n = input.nextInt();
    int[] arr3 = shiftArray(arr1, n);
    System.out.println("Here is the shifted Array: " + Arrays.toString(arr3));
}
```

```java
public static int[] reverseArray(int[] arr) {
    int[] arrShiftDone = new int[arr.length];
    for (int i = 0, j = arrShiftDone.length - 1; i < arr.length; i++, j--) {
        arrShiftDone[j] = arr[i];
    }
    return arrShiftDone;
}
```

```java
public static int[] shiftArray(int[] arr, int shift) {
    int[] arrShiftDone = new int[arr.length];
    shift = shift % arr.length;
    if (shift < 0) {
        shift = arr.length + shift;
    }
    for (int i = 0 + shift, j = 0; j < arr.length; i++, j++) {
        if (i >= arr.length) {
            arrShiftDone[j] = arr[i - arr.length];
        } else {
            arrShiftDone[j] = arr[i];
        }
    }
    return arrShiftDone;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to fix a couple of things:

1. `shift` method never gets called from the `main` method, which means it won't do anything to the array
2. `shift` method should have another argument for the number of places to shift, say `n`
3. In `shift` method, you are using `list` whereas the argument is declared as `arr`

Below is an example method that shifts the array:

```
public static int[] shift(int[] arr, int n) {
    if(n > arr.length) 
        n = n%arr.length;

    int[] result = new int[arr.length];

    for(int i=0; i < n; i++){
        result[i] = arr[arr.length-n+i];
    }

    int j=0;
    for(int i=n; i<arr.length; i++){
        result[i] = arr[j];
        j++;
    }

    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The compilation error is because the variable `list` is unknown. Should be using the argument `arr` instead of `list` inside the method `shift(int[] arr)`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`Arrays.stream(int[],int,int)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#stream-int:A-int-int-) method twice to get two streams with the specified ranges of the array: *near* and *far*, then swap them and [`concat`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#concat-java.util.stream.IntStream-java.util.stream.IntStream-) back into one stream, and thus get a shifted array:

```java
public static int[] shiftArray(int[] arr, int n) {
    return IntStream
            .concat(Arrays.stream(arr, n, arr.length),
                    Arrays.stream(arr, 0, n))
            .toArray();
}
```

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] arr1 = {2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12};

    System.out.println("Source array: " + Arrays.toString(arr1));
    System.out.println("Enter a number: ");

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    int n = input.nextInt();

    int[] arr2 = shiftArray(arr1, n % arr1.length);
    System.out.println("Shifted array: " + Arrays.toString(arr2));
}
```

Output:

```
Source array: [2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12]
Enter a number: 
3
Shifted array: [8, 10, 12, 2, 4, 6]
```

---

<sup>See also: [Place positive numbers before negative](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66147420/14940971)</sup>